# Error 0xC0000138 Ordinal not found in DLL "myApp.exe" when moving code into function

Tags: c++, windows, dll, cmake

I want to try out the Blaze linear algebra library and startet with a simple test programm. It looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <blaze/Blaze.h>

typedef blaze::DynamicVector<int, blaze::columnVector> bdVector;

int main(int argn, char** argc) {

    bdVector a{ 1, 2, 3 };

    std::cout << a+a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This works fine. But when I move the code into a separate function, like this

```
#include <iostream>

#include <blaze/Blaze.h>

typedef blaze::DynamicVector<int, blaze::columnVector> bdVector;

bdVector func(bdVector a, bdVector b) { return a + b; }

int main(int argn, char** argc) {

    bdVector a{ 1, 2, 3 };

    std::cout << func(a,a) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the error

`The Ordinal 968 was not found in DLL "PATH/blaze-test.exe"` It's apparently related to ntdll.dll:

`Exception at 0x00007FFA7128EB78 (ntdll.dll) in blaze-test.exe: 0xC0000138: Ordinal Not Found.`

I didn't find something related when I googled this error, so I hope some here has an idea.

Best regards

ps: Just in case: I used CMake and Visual Studio 2019 and build in both debug and release config (in release its just ordinal 900 instead)

edit: It seems like this is not because of the function. I added this line to the working code

`bdVector b = a;`

and this assignment causes the same error.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when the args are references rather than by-value copies ?

Comment: The same, for pointers as well.

Comment: I'd guess it's finding a different version of the Blaze DLLs than the .lib you're linking against. Why this happens when you move the code is because under the covers you'll be adding a call to a copy or move constructor probably, and that's the ordinal it can't find at runtime. (ntdll will be the place performing the ordinal lookup, and so not part of the problem.) You can probably check this by digging through the .lib you're using, or "dumpbin /exports" on the correct version of the DLL will list exports and ordinals too.

Comment: Blaze is a header only library linked using an interface library in CMake. There are no dll/libs for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It seems as if MKL came with a lib for OpenMP. As a consequence there were two OpenMP libraries due to the find_package(OpenMP) in CMake. It worked with Clang because Clang didn’t find OpenMP.

However I don’t understand why this happend when I used an assignment.I would expect it to happen either always or when I use an operation which uses OpenMP.